# Intuitive charge distribution

Tags: electrostatics, intuition

I often see it stated that excess charge will appear on the surface or excess charge will appear on the **outside** surface and it is causing me some intuitive confusion in some situations if it is always strictly **outside** or depending on situation it could be inside surfaces too?

For example:

If there is a conductive hollow structure s1 with a negative charge q1 on it

[image: s1 hollow blob]

and then another conductive object s2 is added with a positive charge q2 at the center of s1 but the two surfaces are not touching each other.  I assume this causes s1 to polarize to make the E field inside s1 conductor to become zero. I have not added any additional charge to s1 - it's total charge is still (negative) q1

[image: s2 tiny sphere added to center of s1 hollow blob]

My understanding is that the outer object s1 if it had no charge on it would polarize: I would assume negative charge accumulates on the inside surface and positive charge accumulates on the outside so that the an observation from the outside would see a total charge of q2.

However I do not understand what happens if s1 has an existing charge already on it. Does the charge migrate to the inside surface? Or does it remain on the outside surface. I understand the appearance of total charge outside of s1 would appear less than s2 but I am interested in the charge migration to make the E field inside the metal 0.

Or to put it another way, lets say I now add more negative charge to q1 while its in the 2nd state, does the negative charge migrate to the inside surface or remain at the outer surface.

Can I apply a type of intuitive super position and assume the negative charge would remain on the surface because that's what happens when there is no charge in the center? Or is that wrong? Or a better intuitive model exists I should adapt in my head.

Comment: An example: in picture 2 let's add a ground wire to s1, electrons flow in, from the outside it looks neutral .... on the inside there is an E field ... within s1 there is no field, s1 has attained enough electrons to neutralize the outer surface positive charges.

Comment: In the example electrons would repel in S1 .... the surfaces are negative .... each surface having 1/2 of the positive charge of q2 on s2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"lets say I now add more negative charge to q1 while its in the 2nd state, does the negative charge migrate to the inside surface or remain at the outer surface."

It remains on the outer surface.

Imagine a gaussian surface entirely within the conductor S1, and enclosing the cavity. $\vec E$ is zero at all points on this surface (otherwise the free charge carriers would be moving, and we wouldn't have electrostatic conditions). Therefore the electric flux going in or out through this surface is zero. Applying Gauss's law, the total charge enclosed by this surface is zero. Therefore the charge on the inside surface of S1 (your outer conductor) must be equal and opposite to the charge on S2. This is irrespective of whether or not you add extra charge to S1.

You can, if you like, regard the charge on S2 being able to hold in place an equal and opposite charge, no more and no less, on the inner surface of S1, and/or the electric field lines from S2 having to end on an equal charge on the inner surface of S1 but these remarks are hand-wavy compared with the argument in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the inner positively charged point charge (assuming point charge for simplicity) and charge neutral but polarized outer shell, when you add negative charge to the outer shell, (0) the positive side will for sure gradually become less positive. The more difficult question is (1) Would all positive charged surface segment become zero and eventually negatively charged, as one keep adding negative charges? (2) Would the negative surface segmemts remain unchanged until all positive surface disappear first?

(1) Yes, all positively charged surface will eventually become negative as you keep adding negative charge, I think. This is because the limit of (arbitrarily negative outer shell and fixed strength of induction from the positive point charge), would likely behave similar to (fixed negatively charged outer shell and arbitrarily small induction). In the later case, eventually all surface segments would become negatively charged.

(2) I think the negative charge surface segment will change their value as you add more negative charge... Because the neutral-surface-charge-circumference is moving as you add more negative charge to the outer shell. It would be extremely weird for any negative surface segment to remain unchanged.

By the way, one in principle don't need to guess at all. One can solve poisson equation with the appropriate boundary condition, according to the following:

Drill a small hole in the outer shell (to make the topology of the system simpler). Now you have a point charge and a metal chuck. Consider the region outside the metal. Take poisson equation with a point charge in that region, and set the voltage boundary condition around the metal to be a constant value. There is an unique solution of voltage field for this system, and it can always be solved numerically. You can get the exact surface charge density by the strength of the electric field on the surface multiplying permittivity. Integrate the surface charge density to find total charge on the metal. Given this net charge on the metal, the poisson equation give you the exact solution for the voltage/electric field. You can change the boundary condition voltage until the integrated net charge is what you want，you would know the electric field and the surface charge density distribution, given the net charge on the metal.

In specific cases with high symmetry, you can find simple analytic solution. Assume your shell is perfectly spherical symmetric. The electric field inside the shell is simply that of the point charge. The electric field outside of the shell is that of a point charge with the total charge. This gives surface charge density -q1/r^2 on the inner surface and q1+q2/R^2 on the outer surface. Or total charge -q1 on the inner shell and q1+q2 on the outer shell. The inner shell negative surface charge actually remains the same in this perfect sphere example, so my guess (2) is not always true. The outer shell charge q1+q2 changed from positive to negative when q2 becomes more and more negative, so my guess (1) is true... Well actually the reasoning in my guess (1) can also be wrong. Consider we still have positive point charge but we add positive charge to the shell. The inner shell charge doesn't care about q2 at all and will always be negative regardless how much positive charge q2 you place in the shell.